# Conditionally display columns in datagrid jsf

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, datagrid

I'm using datagrid to display list of items. inside the datagrid it is decided condionally to display the column or not. But even if the condition is false and nothing is displayed datagrid still creates an empty div for it which leaves a large gap in between the items. Is there any way I can tackle this.

```
<h:datagrid var="item" value="itemList" columns="{value from some code}" ><h:column rendered="{some condition}" >....... </h:column></h:datagrid>
```

Note: I cannot change the item List because of some dependency in code.

Comment: the problem is when all the columns have `rendered=false`?

Comment: @WoAiNii  rendered can return false or true for any column. So, for each column in which rendered return false no content is displayed but there is an empty space left.

Comment: I don't get it, if a column isn't rendered how can it create a gap? I can't reproduce your problem, can you post a fully reproducible example or at last an image to show the problem?